# How to update charts inside jquery tabs at an interval

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvasjs

I am trying to use jquery tabs with charts but have a problem to automatically update the charts on an interval. I have observed that the charts are only updated when ever I switch from one tab to another and back.
The `$dataPoints1` & `$dataPoints2` are collected from a file and is working very well.

See my tab setup:
[image]

My code until now (the data are in `$dataPoints1` & `$dataPoints2`):

```
<script>
        window.onload = function() {
            var updateInterval = 1500;
            var chart1 = {
                animationEnabled: true,
                zoomEnabled: true,
                theme: "light2",
                title: {
                    text: "Room temperature",
                    fontSize: 22
                },
                axisX:{
                    title: "chart updates every " + updateInterval / 1000 + " secs"
                },
                axisY:{
                    suffix: " C"
                },
                toolTip: {
                    shared: true
                },
                legend: {
                    cursor:"pointer",
                    verticalAlign: "top",
                    fontSize: 18,
                    fontColor: "dimGrey",
                    itemclick : toggleDataSeries1
                },
                data: [{
                    type: "line",
                    yValueFormatString: "##.##",
                    xValueFormatString: "hh:mm:ss TT",
                    showInLegend: true,
                    legendText: "{name} " + yValue1 + " C",
                    toolTipContent: "{y} C",
                    dataPoints: $dataPoints1
                }]
            }
    
            var chart2 = {
                animationEnabled: true,
                zoomEnabled: true,
                theme: "light2",
                title: {
                    text: "Barometric pressure",
                    fontSize: 22
                },
                axisX:{
                    title: "chart updates every " + updateInterval / 1000 + " secs"
                },
                axisY:{
                    suffix: " hPA"
                },
                toolTip: {
                    shared: true
                },
                legend: {
                    cursor:"pointer",
                    verticalAlign: "top",
                    fontSize: 18,
                    fontColor: "dimGrey",
                    itemclick : toggleDataSeries2
                },
                data: [{
                    type: "line",
                    yValueFormatString: "##.##",
                    xValueFormatString: "hh:mm:ss TT",
                    showInLegend: true,
                    legendText: "{name} " + yValue2 + " hPA",
                    toolTipContent: "{y} hPA",
                    dataPoints: $dataPoints2
                }]
            }

            setInterval(function () { updateChart() }, updateInterval);
        
            var xValue1 = $dataPoints1.length;
            var yValue1 = $dataPoints1[$dataPoints1.length - 1].y;
        
            var xValue2 = $dataPoints2.length;
            var yValue2 = $dataPoints2[$dataPoints2.length - 1].y;

            function toggleDataSeries1(e) {
                if (typeof(e.dataSeries.visible) === "undefined" || e.dataSeries.visible) {
                    e.dataSeries.visible = false;
                }
                else {
                    e.dataSeries.visible = true;
                }
                chart1.render();
            }
        
            function toggleDataSeries2(e) {
                if (typeof(e.dataSeries.visible) === "undefined" || e.dataSeries.visible) {
                    e.dataSeries.visible = false;
                }
                else {
                    e.dataSeries.visible = true;
                }
                chart2.render();
            }

            function updateChart() {
                yValue1 += (Math.random() - 0.5) * 0.1;
                yValue2 += (Math.random() - 0.5) * 0.1;
                $dataPoints1.push({ x: xValue1, y: yValue1 });
                $dataPoints2.push({ x: xValue2, y: yValue2 });
                xValue1++;
                xValue2++;
                chart1.options.data[0].legendText = "Temperature " + yValue1.toFixed(2) + " C";
                chart2.options.data[0].legendText = "Barometric " + yValue2.toFixed(2) + " hPA";
                chart1.render();
                chart2.render();
            };
    
            $("#tabs").tabs(
                {
                    create: function (event, ui) {
                        //Render Charts after tabs have been created.
                        $("#chartContainer11").CanvasJSChart(chart1);
                        $("#chartContainer12").CanvasJSChart(chart2);
                    },
                    activate: function (event, ui) {
                        //Updates the chart to its container size if it has changed.
                        ui.newPanel.children().first().CanvasJSChart().render();
                    }
                }
            );
        };
</scritp>

<body>
    <div id="tabs" style="height: 360px">
        <ul>
            <li ><a href="#tabs-1" style="font-size: 12px">Client -1-</a></li>
            <li ><a href="#tabs-2"  style="font-size: 12px">Client -2-</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div id="tabs-1" style="height: 300px">
            <div id="chartContainer11" style="width: 48%; height: 350px;display: inline-block;"></div>
            <div id="chartContainer12" style="width: 48%; height: 350px;display: inline-block;"></div><br/>
            <div id="chartContainer13" style="width: 48%; height: 350px;display: inline-block;"></div>
            <div id="chartContainer14" style="width: 48%; height: 350px;display: inline-block;"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="tabs-2" style="height: 300px">
            <div id="chartContainer21" style="width: 48%; height: 350px;display: inline-block;"></div>
            <div id="chartContainer22" style="width: 48%; height: 350px;display: inline-block;"></div><br/>
            <div id="chartContainer23" style="width: 48%; height: 350px;display: inline-block;"></div>
            <div id="chartContainer24" style="width: 48%; height: 350px;display: inline-block;"></div>
        </div>
    </div>

<script src="https://canvasjs.com/assets/script/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://canvasjs.com/assets/script/jquery-ui.1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://canvasjs.com/assets/script/jquery.canvasjs.min.js"></script>

</body>
```

Where is my mistake?

Update: I took the advise from [@VishwasR](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5808897/vishwas-r) and have a workable solution for now but i do have one more issue. How can I not execute the activate: function (event, ui) part in case Client2 has nothing to show? For now when I switch to Client2 I am getting the below error because no charts are created:

```
Uncaught TypeError: ui.newPanel.children().first().CanvasJSChart() is undefined
```

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have got confused between [chart & chart-options](https://canvasjs.com/docs/charts/basics-of-creating-html5-chart/updating-chart-options/). You are storing options in chart1 & chart2 variables but trying to render chart by calling it as chart1.render() & chart2.render(). Storing chart1 & chart2 soon after creation & updating it after every 1.5seconds seems to work fine. Below is the working code ([JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vishwas_r/46qsf0hw/)).

```js
var updateInterval = 1500;
var dataPoints1 = [], dataPoints2 = [], chart1, chart2;
var options1 = {
  animationEnabled: true,
  zoomEnabled: true,
  theme: "light2",
  title: {
    text: "Room temperature",
    fontSize: 22
  },
  axisX:{
    title: "chart updates every " + updateInterval / 1000 + " secs"
  },
  axisY:{
    suffix: " C"
  },
  toolTip: {
    shared: true
  },
  legend: {
    cursor:"pointer",
    verticalAlign: "top",
    fontSize: 18,
    fontColor: "dimGrey",
    itemclick : toggleDataSeries1
  },
  data: [{
    type: "line",
    yValueFormatString: "##.##",
    xValueFormatString: "hh:mm:ss TT",
    showInLegend: true,
    legendText: "{name} " + yValue1 + " C",
    toolTipContent: "{y} C",
    dataPoints: dataPoints1
  }]
}

var options2 = {
  animationEnabled: true,
  zoomEnabled: true,
  theme: "light2",
  title: {
    text: "Barometric pressure",
    fontSize: 22
  },
  axisX:{
    title: "chart updates every " + updateInterval / 1000 + " secs"
  },
  axisY:{
    suffix: " hPA"
  },
  toolTip: {
    shared: true
  },
  legend: {
    cursor:"pointer",
    verticalAlign: "top",
    fontSize: 18,
    fontColor: "dimGrey",
    itemclick : toggleDataSeries2
  },
  data: [{
    type: "line",
    yValueFormatString: "##.##",
    xValueFormatString: "hh:mm:ss TT",
    showInLegend: true,
    legendText: "{name} " + yValue2 + " hPA",
    toolTipContent: "{y} hPA",
    dataPoints: dataPoints2
  }]
}

function toggleDataSeries1(e) {
  if (typeof(e.dataSeries.visible) === "undefined" || e.dataSeries.visible) {
    e.dataSeries.visible = false;
  }
  else {
    e.dataSeries.visible = true;
  }
  chart1.render();
}

function toggleDataSeries2(e) {
  if (typeof(e.dataSeries.visible) === "undefined" || e.dataSeries.visible) {
    e.dataSeries.visible = false;
  }
  else {
    e.dataSeries.visible = true;
  }
  chart2.render();
}

var xValue1 = 0, yValue1 = 100, xValue2 = 0, yValue2 = 100;
function updateChart() {
  yValue1 += (Math.random() - 0.5) * 0.1;
  yValue2 += (Math.random() - 0.5) * 0.1;
  dataPoints1.push({ x: xValue1, y: yValue1 });
  dataPoints2.push({ x: xValue2, y: yValue2 });
  xValue1++;
  xValue2++;
  chart1.options.data[0].legendText = "Temperature " + yValue1.toFixed(2) + " C";
  chart2.options.data[0].legendText = "Barometric " + yValue2.toFixed(2) + " hPA";
  chart1.render();
  chart2.render();
};

$("#tabs").tabs(
  {
    create: function (event, ui) {
      //Render Charts after tabs have been created.
      $("#chartContainer11").CanvasJSChart(options1);
      $("#chartContainer12").CanvasJSChart(options2);
      chart1 =  $("#chartContainer11").CanvasJSChart();
        chart2 =  $("#chartContainer12").CanvasJSChart();  
      setInterval(function () { updateChart() }, updateInterval);
    },
    activate: function (event, ui) {
      //Updates the chart to its container size if it has changed.
      ui.newPanel.children().first().CanvasJSChart().render();
    }
  }
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://canvasjs.com/assets/script/jquery-ui.1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://canvasjs.com/assets/script/jquery.canvasjs.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://canvasjs.com/assets/css/jquery-ui.1.11.2.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div id="tabs" style="height: 360px">
        <ul>
            <li ><a href="#tabs-1" style="font-size: 12px">Client -1-</a></li>
            <li ><a href="#tabs-2"  style="font-size: 12px">Client -2-</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div id="tabs-1" style="height: 300px">
            <div id="chartContainer11" style="width: 100%; height: 300px;display: inline-block;"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="tabs-2" style="height: 300px">
            <div id="chartContainer12" style="width: 100%; height: 300px;display: inline-block;"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```